# Define a number of points in the plot, matlab

Tags: matlab, random, trigonometry

I need to plot cos-function and choose a `n` points on  the plot.

I have plot a cos function as

```
x = -pi:0.01:pi; 
y=cos(x);
plot(x,y)
```

As a result I have gotten a cos-plot and a set of (x,y). **How can I define , for example, 4 points on this function?**

I was thinking to define a vector with `y` and by using `randi(y)`  and loop , define `n` number of `y`:

```
for i = 1:n
   ind = randperm(numel(y), 1); 
   r(i) = y(ind);
 end
```

It gives me a random choice of the points. **BUT** I need define equal number of point from both side, if the number of point should be even and if it is odd, one point is on the centre.

For example: if i choose 4 points, 2 point will be on the left side, 2 is on the right side.
If the number of point is 5, then one is on the top/middle , 2 point will be on the left side, 2 is on the right side.

How can I implement it in matlab?

Answer (score 2):

Use `linspace` function. The below code will give you 4 points evenly spaced from -pi to pi. (There is a companion function `logspace` that will evenly spaced points in log-space.)

```
x = linspace(-pi,pi,4)
```

That all said, there is another approach which might be helpful if you are plotting functions. The fplot command will look at the function and optimize the number of points so that you get a respectable looking line and you don't have to worry about the number of points.

```
fplot(@(x) cos(x),[-pi pi],'b')
```